# How to send a message when click in an InlineKeyboardButton (Telegram & Python)

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm using TelegramBotAPI library to create a telegram bot in python.
I have this code to show an Inline Keyboard

```
def gen_markup():
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row_width = 2
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", callback_data="cb_yes"),
                               InlineKeyboardButton("No", callback_data="cb_no"))
    return markup
```

And after a function to see this keyboard when you send a command.
I have also this code to do an action when press on a button.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def send_welcome(call):
    if call.data == "cb_yes":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "YES")
    elif call.data == "cb_no":
        bot.send_message(call.id, "NO")
```

This only show the text on the screen and after some seconds it disappear. How can I send instead a text message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CallbackQuery` contains the message object which holds chat id that can be used with `send_message()`

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query(call):
    if call.data == "cb_yes":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Answer is Yes")
    elif call.data == "cb_no":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "This is a message")
```

Comment: And how can I send the message when the user click in the button? I tried some methods but they don't work. I think because bot.callback_query and bot.message_handler (to send a message) conflict. Thanks

Comment: @enricozz just try the code sent by w4rr1or and you'll see that it will work and will send the message